# sails.js: Model definition of enum - dynamic list of values

Tags: javascript, enums, sails.js, models

For the following model definition in sails.js:

```
attributes: {
  // status field
  status: {
    type: 'string',
    enum: ['verified', 'pending', 'completed']
  },

  // OS
  os: {
    type: 'string',
    // can we get these values come from another table, for ex?
    enum: ['linux', 'windows', 'macosx', 'android', 'ios']
  }
}
```

It so happens that these enum options are not always static, and this can be dynamic, where the options could come from another table, for ex.

Looking for suggestions to accomplish, where the enum values can be taken from another table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a custom method on before/afterValidate that checks the value against dynamic values found in another table. I suggested before/afterValidate because they would run on both update/create.

Comment: I have created a hook to achieve this. In each of the model's beforeValidate, I intend to call the hook's method which will update the dynamic values to the model. But within the beforeValidate method, I don't know which model for which it is executed. I did check `this` within beforeValidate method, but no help there. @Meeker: Can you guide please?

Comment: Are you creating this in each of the model's beforeValidate, can you specifiy the model when you call the function in beforeValidate. I'm not sure I understand your setup, if you could post code somewhere . . . pastebin or something.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Yes, that is an option where in each model, I can specify the model name while calling the hook function. Now, I see that my question does not make any sense! Sorry.. Anyway, I have now figured a way to add a callback automatically. The entire hook, as it stands now, is at https://gist.github.com/rsmoorthy/3f133a5f76744f3cf5bb